# Change the default JVM version in matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jvm, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

i am trying to change the default JVM from matlab but it didn't work.

```
>> !java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
>> !/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
>> !export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0_65-b14-468`
>> !java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

i am doing this because the MCC command doesn't work with java 1.8.

what i have to do to change the default JVM? 
iam working on OS X 10.10.3 with Matlab r2011a

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Matlab is shipped with its own version of JVM and does not respect `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable. Instead, you need to create `MATLAB_JAVA` environmental variable, set it to JRE/JDK directory, and then start Matlab.