# configure settings for Installing Octave 4.0.3 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, octave

So i am following steps to install the latest version of octave from [here](http://www.schoeps.org/home/2015/06/five-simple-instructions-to-compile-octave-4-on-ubuntu/).

```
sudo apt-get install g++ gcc gfortran make autoconf automake bison flex gperf gzip icoutils librsvg2-bin libtool perl rsync tar

sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpcre3-dev libarpack2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev epstool libfftw3-dev transfig libfltk1.3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgl2ps-dev libglpk-dev libreadline-dev gnuplot libgraphicsmagick++-dev libhdf5-serial-dev openjdk-9-jdk libsndfile1-dev llvm-dev lpr texinfo libgl1-mesa-dev libosmesa6-dev pstoedit portaudio19-dev libqhull-dev libqrupdate-dev libqscintilla2-dev libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-network libqtgui4 libsuitesparse-dev libxft-dev zlib1g-dev

cd ~/Downloads/
wget -c ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf octave-4.0.3.tar.gz
cd octave-4.0.3

./configure --prefix=/opt/octave-4.0.3 CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/hdf5/serial JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
```

Here i get message as:

```
configure: WARNING: Java version is too old (< 1.5).  Octave will not be able to call Java methods.
```

But i have installed the latest version of `openjdk` via `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk`. So why do i get this message? Is it because i used the `JAVA_HOME` flag in configure settings?

Moreover, when i run `make check`, tests tell that out of 874 tests, 207 could not be run because of lacking dependencies. The rest could be run and passed. Therefore, i have a lot of dependencies issues. My question is what is the best configure settings to install 100% features of octave 4.0.3 in ubuntu 16.04? So that after this when i do `make install`, i have the full latest version without any glitch.

Comment: What's wrong with the version from apt-get?  http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems

Comment: @cricket_007 I read [elsewhere](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645600/how-to-install-octave-4-0-0-in-ubuntu-14-04) that from `apt-get` one gets significantly older versions for octave. that's why i tried source.

Comment: @user_1_1_1 Then I suggest installing `octave` from its official PPA at https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable. You can of course still compile and install from source if you insist, but it is not particularly straightforward as you have realized.

Comment: I see... The PPA does have version 4.0.2, though.  In any case, have you tried using Java 8? Or been able to find how that error appears? https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Comment: @cricket_007 I only have openjdk 9 on my system. This is what i also specified in the JAVA_HOME flag. Are you suggesting me to install openjdk 8 and pass that to JAVA_HOME flag?

Comment: I'm just thinking that Java 9 isn't official yet, so Octave may not detect it

Comment: Have you had a look at config.log to figure out why configure thinks it found an old version?

Comment: You are using Ubuntu 16.04.  That version of Ubuntu already packages [Octave 4.0.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/octave) which is the latest minor version of Octave (the latest patch version is 4.0.3 though).

Comment: @user_1_1_1 when you perform the ./configure step, there is a summary at the end. Does it report any problems?  Also, I agree with carandraug, you're probably not going to notice any difference from 4.0.0 to 4.0.3 at this stage. Save yourself the hassle and install from the repositories :)

Comment: You need to install openjdk-8 instead. In configure.ac, take a look at the line that checks "java_version" -- it runs the command "java -version" and then parses the output. If you do this after installing openjdk-8, you get "1.8.0..." If you do this after installing openjdk-9, there is no version number. That's why the test fails. (This is based on installing Octave 4.2, where I also ran into the java version problem.)